# Rails 3 - how to use autocomplete with textarea instead of classic text input?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, textarea

I am playing with [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) gem and it works me pretty well. Here is an example, how looks my autocomplete input:

```
= f.autocomplete_field :interest, autocomplete_interest_users_path, :"data-delimiter" => ','
```

Because many times I need to write lots of words into the input, that's why would be better to use **textarea** instead of default **input**, but how to do that? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you want to auto-complete the entire input or individual words within the input?

Comment: I am not sure if I know what you mean - I wanna use auto-complete with  textarea, not with **input type=text**

Comment: Do you want to select a value for the entire text, or do you want to select values for words entered within the text.

Comment: Values for words entered within the text.

Comment: @SteveJorgensen Can you help, if i need entire text input to be autocompleted. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20594445/simple-form-input-as-both-text-and-autocomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like http://rightjs.org/ui/tags/demo perhaps? There's an article on making this work with Rails at http://st-on-it.blogspot.com/2011/04/making-tags-with-rails-and-rightjs.html .

Comment: Exactly this is what I need, but there could be a little problem, because as my default JS framework I use jQuery, so how can cooperate these two frameworks with together?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it with jQuery:

Add this as a helper:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module FormHelper

      def autocomplete_text_area(object_name, method, source, options ={})
        options["data-autocomplete"] = source
        text_area(object_name, method, rewrite_autocomplete_option(options))
      end
    end
  end

  class ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
    def autocomplete_text_area(method, source, options = {})
      @template.autocomplete_text_area(@object_name, method, source, objectify_options(options))
    end
  end
end
```

This is how you would extend form helpers in Rails. What we're doing here is adding our own method which we can call in our view.

Now, add this to one of your javascript files:

```
 $('textarea[data-autocomplete]').railsAutocomplete()
```

This sets up the autocomplete js script to listen and respond to our textarea.

And you should now be able to do something like this in your view:

```
f.autocomplete_text_area :name, autocomplete_menu_item_name_menus_path, placeholder: "Menu Item Name", class: 'input-lg menu_item', size: "45x2"
```