# Simple_form input as both text and autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, simple-form

I am using gem 'simple_form', '2.0' and gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', '1.0.10'.

I am unable to make a string field accept two ':as' arguments.

```
<%= f.input :product_description , :url => autocomplete_product_name_products_path,
:as => :text, :as => :autocomplete, :placeholder=>"Type product name",
:input_html => {:class =>"span2", :rows => 6}, wrapper: :inline_label, label:false  %>
```

If I remove :as => :text, the auto-complete part works but ':rows => 6' part fail.

And if I keep both, I get 6 rows but the auto-complete stops working.

I need this field to have have multiple rows as well as auto-complete.
This is a really silly question but I am stuck. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Simple Form doesn't define an `autocomplete` input. But if you need an autocomplete input and the text type I think you can do:

```
f.input :product_description ,
:url => autocomplete_product_name_products_path,
:as => :autocomplete,
:placeholder=>"Type product name",
:input_html => {:class =>"span2", :rows => 6, type => :text },
wrapper: :inline_label, label: false
```

Comment: Thank a lot for replying.
Just tried this. The autocomplete part is working but still can't get multiple rows.

Comment: I just need the field to have multiple rows, can it be done without making it a text field?

Comment: If the autocomplete input is not changing the `type` attribute the code I posted should work. Maybe you should ask the autocomplete gem authors.

Comment: How did you go with this? Any tips for those that follow in your footsteps? thx